# How can I get the precise common "max.distance" value for fuzzy string matching using agrep?

Tags: r, string-matching, agrep

I am trying to figure out the best precision for fuzzy string matching between two string names using agrep.

However, I will need to choose one precision "max.distance" to apply the same across all strings I am trying to match since the amount of string is huge.
It won't be possible to choose the best precision value "max.distance" for every each string I am trying to match.

For instance, let's say I use the precision "max.distance" as "0.2", "0.1", and "0.05" for each "BANK OF AMERICA CORP" and "1st Capital Bank".

First, the below is for "BANK OF AMERICA CORP" for "max.distance" of "0.2","0.1", and "0.05":

```
    > agrep("BANK OF AMERICA CORP",C1999_0[,2],ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE,fixed = TRUE,max.distance =0.2)
     [1] "BANK OF AMERICA/PRIVATE BANK WEST"   "BANK OF AMERICA SECURITIES"         
     [3] "BANK OF AMERICA SEC LLC"             "BANK OF AMERICA SECURITIES LLC"     
     [5] "BANK OF AMERICA NT & SA"             "BANK OF AMERICA CORP"               
     [7] "ALLIANZ OF AMERICA CORP"             "Bank of America Securities/Vice Pre"
     [9] "Bank of America Securities/Investme" "Bank of America/President"          
    [11] "Bank of America Securities LLC/Prin" "Bank of America Securities LLC/Mana"
    [13] "Bank of America Securities LLC/Inve" "Bank of America Securities/Principa"
    [15] "Bank of America Securities LLC/Bank" "Bank of America Sec/Investment Bank"
    [17] "Bank Of America Securities/Managing" "Bank of America/Chairman--Midwest A"
    [19] "Bank of America Securities LLC/Vice" "Bank of America Corporation/Sales C"
    [21] "Bank of America Securities/Broker"   "Bank of America Corporation/Banker" 
    [23] "Bank of America Corporation/Senior"  "Bank of America Securities/Equity R"
    [25] "Bank of America Corporation/Vice Ch" "BANK OF AMERICA CORPORATION"        
    [27] "BANK OF AMERICA HEADQUARTERS"        "BANK OF AMERICA ADMINISTRATION"     
    [29] "BANK OF AMERICA N A"                 "Bank of America/Commercial Banking" 
    [31] "Bank of America Sec./Investment Ban"
    > 
    > agrep("BANK OF AMERICA CORP",C1999_0[,2],ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE,fixed = TRUE,max.distance =0.1)
    [1] "BANK OF AMERICA CORP"                "ALLIANZ OF AMERICA CORP"            
    [3] "Bank of America Corporation/Sales C" "Bank of America Corporation/Banker" 
    [5] "Bank of America Corporation/Senior"  "Bank of America Corporation/Vice Ch"
    [7] "BANK OF AMERICA CORPORATION"        
    > 
    > agrep("BANK OF AMERICA CORP",C1999_0[,2],ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE,fixed = TRUE,max.distance =0.05)
    [1] "BANK OF AMERICA CORP"                "Bank of America Corporation/Sales C"
    [3] "Bank of America Corporation/Banker"  "Bank of America Corporation/Senior" 
    [5] "Bank of America Corporation/Vice Ch" "BANK OF AMERICA CORPORATION"
```

Then below is the "1st Capital Bank" for "max.distance" of "0.2", "0.1", and "0.05":

```
    > agrep("1st Capital Bank",C1999_0[,2],ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE,fixed = TRUE,max.distance =0.2)
      [1] "HURST CAPITAL PARTNERS"             
      [2] "SOY CAPITAL BANK"                   
      [3] "FIRST CAPITOL BANK OF VICTOR"       
      [4] "OSTERWEIS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"       
      [5] "1ST NATIONAL BANK"                  
      [6] "FIRST CAPITAL BANK"                 
      [7] "SEATTLE 1ST NAT'L BANK"             
      [8] "FIELD POINT CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"     
      [9] "SUMMERSET CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"       
     [10] "AMERIQUEST CAPITAL ASSOC"           
     [11] "BB&T CAPITAL MARKETS"               
     [12] "HUGHES CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"          
     [13] "WELLS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"           
     [14] "SUPERIOR ST CAPITAL ADVISORS"       
     [15] "ORMES CAPITAL MARKETS INC"          
     [16] "1ST NAT'L BANK OF IL"               
     [17] "ADVENT CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"          
     [18] "1ST CAPITOL BANK"                   
     [19] "BIONDI REISS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"    
     [20] "CCYBYS CAPITAL MARKETS"             
     [21] "SEACOAST CAPITAL PARTNERS"          
     [22] "DOUGLAS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"         
     [23] "HIGHFIELDS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"      
     [24] "PRECEPT CAPITAL MANAGEMENT LP"      
     [25] "AUGUST CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"          
     [26] "SAKSA CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"           
     [27] "IMS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"             
     [28] "TRENT CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"           
     [29] "Ormes Capital Management"           
     [30] "GARNET CAPITAL MANAGEMENT LLC"      
     [31] "INTERFASE CAPITAL MANAGERS"         
     [32] "RJS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT INC"         
     [33] "1ST NATIONAL BANK OF DE KALB"       
     [34] "1ST NAT'L BANK OF PHILLIPS CO"      
     [35] "1ST NAT'L BANK OF OKLAHOMA"         
     [36] "PROGRESS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT INC"    
     [37] "CAPITAL BANK & TRUST"               
     [38] "1ST NATL BANK"                      
     [39] "ASB Capital Management/Real Estate" 
     [40] "Sears Capital Management"           
     [41] "Osterweis Capital Management/Invest"
     [42] "Cerberus Capital Management LP/Asse"
     [43] "LVS Capital Management/President"   
     [44] "1st Central Bank/Banker"            
     [45] "Summit Capital Management"          
     [46] "Orwes Capital Markets/Stockbroker"  
     [47] "Ormes Capital Management/Investment"
     [48] "Nevis Capital Management/Investment"
     [49] "Duncan Hurst Capital Management"    
     [50] "Progress Capital Management/Preside"
     [51] "Cerberus Capital Management LP"     
     [52] "Wit Capital/Banker"                 
     [53] "Ormes Capital Markets Inc."         
     [54] "Ormes Capital Markets/President & C"
     [55] "Berents & Hess Capital Management"  
     [56] "Progress Capital Management/Venture"
     [57] "First Capital Bank of KY"           
     [58] "Foothill Capital/Banker"            
     [59] "Pequot Capital Management/Equity Re"
     [60] "First Dominion Capital/Banking"     
     [61] "Greenwhich Capital/Banker"          
     [62] "Veritas Capital Management/Banker"  
     [63] "Veritas Capital Management/Investme"
     [64] "Lesese Capital Management/Investmen"
     [65] "Douglas Capital Management/Investme"
     [66] "FIRST NATINAL BANK OF AMARILLO"     
     [67] "NEVIS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"           
     [68] "VERITAS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"         
     [69] "SIEBERT CAPITAL MARKETS"            
     [70] "HOURGLASS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"       
     [71] "1ST NATIONAL BANK DALHART"          
     [72] "TEXAS CAPITAL BANK"                 
     [73] "NICHOLAS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"        
     [74] "CERBUS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"          
     [75] "CROESUS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"         
     [76] "EAST WEST CAPITAL ASSOCIATES INC"   
     [77] "PRENDERGAST CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"     
     [78] "NANTUCKET CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"       
     [79] "1ST NATIONAL BANK TEMPLE"           
     [80] "ENTRUST CAPITAL INC"                
     [81] "1ST NATIONAL BANK OF IL"            
     [82] "SIMMS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"           
     [83] "FIRST CAPITAL ADVISORS"             
     [84] "FIRST CAPITAL MANAGEMENT LTD"       
     [85] "1ST NATIONAL BANK & TRUST"          
     [86] "PENTECOST CAPITAL MANAGEMENT INC"   
     [87] "EAST-WEST CAPITAL ASSOCIATES"       
     [88] "1ST NAT'L BANK OF JOLIET"           
     [89] "FIRST CAPITOL BANK OF VICTO"        
     [90] "FIRST CAPITAL FINANCIAL"            
     [91] "PACIFIC COAST CAPITAL PARTNERS"     
     [92] "FIRST CAPITOL BANK"                 
     [93] "FIRST CAPITAL ENGINEERING"          
     [94] "MIDWEST CAPITOL MANAGEMENT"         
     [95] "PEQUOT CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"          
     [96] "AGGOTT CAPITAL MANAGEMENT"          
     [97] "SIMMS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT INC"       
     [98] "PHILLIPS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT LLC"    
     [99] "1ST NATIONAL BANK OF COLD SP"       
    [100] "SOY CAPITOL BANK"                   
    > 
    > agrep("1st Capital Bank",C1999_0[,2],ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE,fixed = TRUE,max.distance =0.1)
    [1] "FIRST CAPITOL BANK OF VICTOR" "FIRST CAPITAL BANK"          
    [3] "1ST CAPITOL BANK"             "First Capital Bank of KY"    
    [5] "TEXAS CAPITAL BANK"           "FIRST CAPITOL BANK OF VICTO" 
    [7] "FIRST CAPITOL BANK"          
    > 
    > agrep("1st Capital Bank",C1999_0[,2],ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE,fixed = TRUE,max.distance =0.05)
    [1] "FIRST CAPITAL BANK"       "1ST CAPITOL BANK"        
    [3] "First Capital Bank of KY"
```

As you can see, it's really difficult to find the common precision value for "max.distance" to apply for every each string such as "BANK OF AMERICA CORP" and "1st Capital Bank". Also I have far much more firm names other than these two which is the reason why I am having difficulty in finding the common precision value and command for fuzzy string match.

The original data file for C1999_0 is too huge to attach so I think only using the output values as shown above would be sufficient to replicate.

I know there are several sub categories to manipulate such as cost, substitutions, insertion, etc. but they did not make much difference with only changing the "max.distance" value itself.

I would really appreciate if I can get help on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems possible that this is an unsolvable problem as stated, that there isn't one max.distance that will work well for all input strings.

It might be worth trying a method like [tf-idf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidytext/vignettes/tf_idf.html) to identify the unusualness of your strings and scale your max.distance to that. So "Ziggurat Mutual" might be given more leeway for variation than "First Bank National" which is more generic.

You might also consider using the fuzzyjoin package, which offers some quick ways to try different options. For instance you might try:

```
df <- c("HURST CAPITAL PARTNERS", "SOY CAPITAL BANK", "FIRST CAPITOL BANK OF VICTOR", "OSTERWEIS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "1ST NATIONAL BANK", "FIRST CAPITAL BANK", "SEATTLE 1ST NAT'L BANK", "FIELD POINT CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "SUMMERSET CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "AMERIQUEST CAPITAL ASSOC", "BB&T CAPITAL MARKETS", "HUGHES CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "WELLS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "SUPERIOR ST CAPITAL ADVISORS", "ORMES CAPITAL MARKETS INC", "1ST NAT'L BANK OF IL", "ADVENT CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "1ST CAPITOL BANK", "BIONDI REISS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "CCYBYS CAPITAL MARKETS", "SEACOAST CAPITAL PARTNERS", "DOUGLAS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "HIGHFIELDS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "PRECEPT CAPITAL MANAGEMENT LP", "AUGUST CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "SAKSA CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "IMS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "TRENT CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "Ormes Capital Management", "GARNET CAPITAL MANAGEMENT LLC", "INTERFASE CAPITAL MANAGERS", "RJS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT INC", "1ST NATIONAL BANK OF DE KALB", "1ST NAT'L BANK OF PHILLIPS CO", "1ST NAT'L BANK OF OKLAHOMA", "PROGRESS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT INC", "CAPITAL BANK & TRUST", "1ST NATL BANK", "ASB Capital Management/Real Estate", "Sears Capital Management", "Osterweis Capital Management/Invest", "Cerberus Capital Management LP/Asse", "LVS Capital Management/President", "1st Central Bank/Banker", "Summit Capital Management", "Orwes Capital Markets/Stockbroker", "Ormes Capital Management/Investment", "Nevis Capital Management/Investment", "Duncan Hurst Capital Management", "Progress Capital Management/Preside", "Cerberus Capital Management LP", "Wit Capital/Banker", "Ormes Capital Markets Inc.", "Ormes Capital Markets/President & C", "Berents & Hess Capital Management", "Progress Capital Management/Venture", "First Capital Bank of KY", "Foothill Capital/Banker", "Pequot Capital Management/Equity Re", "First Dominion Capital/Banking", "Greenwhich Capital/Banker", "Veritas Capital Management/Banker", "Veritas Capital Management/Investme", "Lesese Capital Management/Investmen", "Douglas Capital Management/Investme", "FIRST NATINAL BANK OF AMARILLO", "NEVIS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "VERITAS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "SIEBERT CAPITAL MARKETS", "HOURGLASS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "1ST NATIONAL BANK DALHART", "TEXAS CAPITAL BANK", "NICHOLAS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "CERBUS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "CROESUS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "EAST WEST CAPITAL ASSOCIATES INC", "PRENDERGAST CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "NANTUCKET CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "1ST NATIONAL BANK TEMPLE", "ENTRUST CAPITAL INC", "1ST NATIONAL BANK OF IL", "SIMMS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "FIRST CAPITAL ADVISORS", "FIRST CAPITAL MANAGEMENT LTD", "1ST NATIONAL BANK & TRUST", "PENTECOST CAPITAL MANAGEMENT INC", "EAST-WEST CAPITAL ASSOCIATES", "1ST NAT'L BANK OF JOLIET", "FIRST CAPITOL BANK OF VICTO", "FIRST CAPITAL FINANCIAL", "PACIFIC COAST CAPITAL PARTNERS", "FIRST CAPITOL BANK", "FIRST CAPITAL ENGINEERING", "MIDWEST CAPITOL MANAGEMENT", "PEQUOT CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "AGGOTT CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "SIMMS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT INC", "PHILLIPS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT LLC", "1ST NATIONAL BANK OF COLD SP", "SOY CAPITOL BANK")

library(dplyr); library(fuzzyjoin)
df <- df %>% as_data_frame()

df %>%
  # Allowable methods include osa, lv, dl, hamming, lcs, qgram, 
  #    cosine, jaccard, jw, soundex
  fuzzyjoin::stringdist_inner_join(df, method = "lv", distance_col = "distance", max_dist = 4) %>%
  filter(distance > 0)

Joining by: "value"
# A tibble: 70 x 3
   value.x                      value.y                     distance
   <chr>                        <chr>                          <dbl>
 1 SOY CAPITAL BANK             1ST CAPITOL BANK                   4
 2 SOY CAPITAL BANK             SOY CAPITOL BANK                   1
 3 FIRST CAPITOL BANK OF VICTOR FIRST CAPITOL BANK OF VICTO        1
 4 1ST NATIONAL BANK            1ST NATL BANK                      4
 5 FIRST CAPITAL BANK           1ST CAPITOL BANK                   4
 6 FIRST CAPITAL BANK           FIRST CAPITOL BANK                 1
 7 HUGHES CAPITAL MANAGEMENT    DOUGLAS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT         4
 8 HUGHES CAPITAL MANAGEMENT    AUGUST CAPITAL MANAGEMENT          4
 9 WELLS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT     IMS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT             4
10 WELLS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT     NEVIS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT           3
```

...to experiment with potential non-exact matches among your example list.

Comment: Thank you but may I have your idea in an executable form if you don't mind? Unfortunately, this form does not seemed to be replicable..

Comment: Edited my answer to include library calls and to convert string to data frame before the fuzzyjoin.

Comment: Thank you. So if I am correct, does your method take the entire string data such as "df" as you show and search within this same string data to calculate the distance within itself? If so, is value.x the original data and value.y is the suggested unique string data they find? Also, does it also ignore the capitals as I need?

Comment: Yes. value.y are the other possible matches in the list that aren't exactly the same as value.x (since the last line filters those out), but are within the criteria of the fuzzyjoin. If you want to ignore capitalization, you might make your comparisons between upper-case versions of the names, e.g. `df <- data.frame(name = "Hurst Capital Partners");
df$upper <- toupper(df$name)`

Comment: Oh I mean I am trying to match strings ignoring whether it is large or small capital letters. I am not trying to match among the upper letters or lower letters as you say. Am I right how I understand your message?

Comment: Besides may I know why “1ST CAPITOL BANK” appears twice on value.y?

Comment: In this case, it's saying that it is distance 4 from SOY CAPITAL BANK as well as 4 from FIRST CAPITAL BANK. Each row is a paired relationship between two names.

Comment: Ah ok. So each row comparison gives out the distance numbers. Then value.x is the original data and value.y is the possible match producing each distance for each row all the time. Thank you! Lastly if I am not regarding any letter sizes e.g. if I assume “boy” and “BOy” to be the same, shall I just follow the method above without using any upper case version you suggested later?

Comment: If I am trying to drop some useless strings before matching, what method would you recommend?

Answer (score 3):

An issue with `agrep` is that it is like `grep` as documented in `help("grep")`

> Since someone who read the description carelessly even filed a bug report on it, do note that this matches substrings of each element of `x` (just as `grep` does) and not whole elements. See also `adist` in package **utils**, which optionally returns the offsets of the matched substrings.

This seem to be the issue in your latter example since of you have many names that contains "Capital" or "Bank" or both. What I would do, is to use to compute the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) (which is what `agrep` does or a generalized version and **only for substrings**) and take the ones with shortest distance. E.g.,

```r
C1999 <- c("HURST CAPITAL PARTNERS", "SOY CAPITAL BANK", "FIRST CAPITOL BANK OF VICTOR", "OSTERWEIS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "1ST NATIONAL BANK", "FIRST CAPITAL BANK", "SEATTLE 1ST NAT'L BANK", "FIELD POINT CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "SUMMERSET CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "AMERIQUEST CAPITAL ASSOC", "BB&T CAPITAL MARKETS", "HUGHES CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "WELLS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "SUPERIOR ST CAPITAL ADVISORS", "ORMES CAPITAL MARKETS INC", "1ST NAT'L BANK OF IL", "ADVENT CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "1ST CAPITOL BANK", "BIONDI REISS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "CCYBYS CAPITAL MARKETS", "SEACOAST CAPITAL PARTNERS", "DOUGLAS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "HIGHFIELDS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "PRECEPT CAPITAL MANAGEMENT LP", "AUGUST CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "SAKSA CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "IMS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "TRENT CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "Ormes Capital Management", "GARNET CAPITAL MANAGEMENT LLC", "INTERFASE CAPITAL MANAGERS", "RJS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT INC", "1ST NATIONAL BANK OF DE KALB", "1ST NAT'L BANK OF PHILLIPS CO", "1ST NAT'L BANK OF OKLAHOMA", "PROGRESS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT INC", "CAPITAL BANK & TRUST", "1ST NATL BANK", "ASB Capital Management/Real Estate", "Sears Capital Management", "Osterweis Capital Management/Invest", "Cerberus Capital Management LP/Asse", "LVS Capital Management/President", "1st Central Bank/Banker", "Summit Capital Management", "Orwes Capital Markets/Stockbroker", "Ormes Capital Management/Investment", "Nevis Capital Management/Investment", "Duncan Hurst Capital Management", "Progress Capital Management/Preside", "Cerberus Capital Management LP", "Wit Capital/Banker", "Ormes Capital Markets Inc.", "Ormes Capital Markets/President & C", "Berents & Hess Capital Management", "Progress Capital Management/Venture", "First Capital Bank of KY", "Foothill Capital/Banker", "Pequot Capital Management/Equity Re", "First Dominion Capital/Banking", "Greenwhich Capital/Banker", "Veritas Capital Management/Banker", "Veritas Capital Management/Investme", "Lesese Capital Management/Investmen", "Douglas Capital Management/Investme", "FIRST NATINAL BANK OF AMARILLO", "NEVIS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "VERITAS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "SIEBERT CAPITAL MARKETS", "HOURGLASS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "1ST NATIONAL BANK DALHART", "TEXAS CAPITAL BANK", "NICHOLAS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "CERBUS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "CROESUS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "EAST WEST CAPITAL ASSOCIATES INC", "PRENDERGAST CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "NANTUCKET CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "1ST NATIONAL BANK TEMPLE", "ENTRUST CAPITAL INC", "1ST NATIONAL BANK OF IL", "SIMMS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "FIRST CAPITAL ADVISORS", "FIRST CAPITAL MANAGEMENT LTD", "1ST NATIONAL BANK & TRUST", "PENTECOST CAPITAL MANAGEMENT INC", "EAST-WEST CAPITAL ASSOCIATES", "1ST NAT'L BANK OF JOLIET", "FIRST CAPITOL BANK OF VICTO", "FIRST CAPITAL FINANCIAL", "PACIFIC COAST CAPITAL PARTNERS", "FIRST CAPITOL BANK", "FIRST CAPITAL ENGINEERING", "MIDWEST CAPITOL MANAGEMENT", "PEQUOT CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "AGGOTT CAPITAL MANAGEMENT", "SIMMS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT INC", "PHILLIPS CAPITAL MANAGEMENT LLC", "1ST NATIONAL BANK OF COLD SP", "SOY CAPITOL BANK")

func <- function(x, y, tol = 0L){
  require(stringdist)
  dista <- stringdist::stringdist(x, y, method = "lv")
  min_dista <- min(dista)
  y[dista <= min_dista + tol]
}
func("1st Capital Bank", C1999)
#R [1] "Wit Capital/Banker"
func("1st Capital Bank", C1999, 4L)
#R [1] "Wit Capital/Banker"       "First Capital Bank of KY"
func("1st Capital Bank", C1999, 10L)
#R  [1] "SOY CAPITAL BANK"           "1ST NATIONAL BANK"         
#R  [3] "FIRST CAPITAL BANK"         "1ST CAPITOL BANK"          
#R  [5] "Ormes Capital Management"   "1ST NATL BANK"             
#R  [7] "Sears Capital Management"   "1st Central Bank/Banker"   
#R  [9] "Summit Capital Management"  "Wit Capital/Banker"        
#R [11] "Ormes Capital Markets Inc." "First Capital Bank of KY"  
#R [13] "Foothill Capital/Banker"    "Greenwhich Capital/Banker" 
#R [15] "TEXAS CAPITAL BANK"         "FIRST CAPITOL BANK"        
#R [17] "SOY CAPITOL BANK" 

# ignoring cases
func <- function(x, y, tol = 0L){
  require(stringdist)
  dista <- stringdist::stringdist(tolower(x), tolower(y), method = "lv")
  min_dista <- min(dista)
  y[dista <= min_dista + tol]
}
func("1st Capital Bank", C1999, 0L)
#R [1] "1ST CAPITOL BANK"
```

The `tol` parameter in the `func` controls the if you want to include examples that are `tol` further away from the minimum Levenshtein distance. I see that I did not answer exactly what you asked for (*How can I get the precise common “max.distance” value for fuzzy string matching using `agrep`?*) but I think my answer might be what you are looking for.

I use `stringdist::stringdist` instead of `adist` since the former seems to be faster. It can still be a bit slow and I wish there where an R package where you could set a maximum distance but I have not come across such a package. This could make the computation of the (then capped) Levenshtein distance much faster.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. When I have massive data to match, however, I find so many "NA"s that I cannot even see the ones that are matched unfortunately. Is there a way to sort out the ones that shows the matching ones? Or is this massive "NA" I get is some sort of an error when I use the data straight from "read.table" command?

Comment: So do you have `NA`s in the data you pass to the function or is the `stringdist::stringdist` that returns `NA`s?

Comment: I also find that when my change my data length to be different, the results are not cumulative. For instance if I search through original data C1999[1:10], this gives different and not cumulative results from when I search through C1999[1:100]. I think this is something a problem I'm afraid.

Comment: It is stringdist::stringdist that returns NAs. My data has no NAs at all.

Comment: The function returns you the ones with the minimum distance (or `tol` from that) so it will change if you add new observations one of which has a better match. E.g., as above where "`1ST CAPITOL BANK`" is the exact match. I gather you are looking for matches so it seems desirable to me to disregard poor matches if you find a good one. Why would you bother looking at other examples if you have `"1ST CAPITOL BANK"`? E.g., consider `func("1st Capital Bank", C1999[70:80], 4L)` versus `func("1st Capital Bank", C1999, 4L)`.

Comment: Regarding the `NA`s, can you provide an example where this happens? If not, then try to replace `stringdist::stringdist` with `adist`.

Comment: I do though see that the match actually reads `"CAPITOL"` and not `"CAPITAL"`.

Comment: When I use adist as you mentioned, the NAs still happen when I run my entire sample which has 213998 rows. However, if I run until 80000 rows it gives out the results.

Comment: Also I would rather go for your second function ignoring the cases which seems more fitting to my purpose. Ideally, FIRST CAPITAL BANK would also need to be in as an output while the example is only showing 1ST CAPITOL BANK which is fine but missing the  FIRST CAPITAL BANK. So I do not know the exact advantage compared to agrep function I'm afraid.

Comment: The advantage is that `agrep` looks at **substrings** as I write. E.g, `agrep("1st Capital Bank", "1ST CAPITOL BANK", max.distance = 1L, ignore.case = TRUE)` and `agrep("1st Capital Bank", "1ST CAPITOL BANK of some country I have never heard of", max.distance = 1L, ignore.case = TRUE)` both give you a match. That is why you get such a long output, many of which seems unrelated. The solution I show looks at **the entire string**.

Comment: Ok. but when I run more than 80000 rows, it gives out excessive NAs that I cannot even find the matched ones at all. Will this need smaller data amount to run your code?

Comment: Please, provide an example where this happens. I have no idea what is going wrong otherwise.

Comment: I hope I can provide but I'm afraid this web sheet won't allow pasting more than 80000 rows of data.

Comment: By the way, isn’t my agrep giving a better result than function you defined above? I'm afraid I also find this in general.

Comment: Do notice that the answer you accepted essentially does what I have proposed but within tidy framework (the `tol` parameter is the `max_dist` in [Jon Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52509220/5861244]) answer). So I guess you changed your mind regarding:" _Isn’t my agrep giving a better result than function you defined above? I'm afraid I also find this in general._"